# Visual Studio не находит ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: visual-studio, c#

День добрый.

Visual Studio никак не хочет находить ManagementObjectSearcher. Чего только не пробовал. Изменял версию .NET, импортировал разные вещи. Без толку.

Решил проверить инфу из одной статейки, да и юзануть для себя.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher11 =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher11.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----------- Win32_VideoController instance -------");
                Console.WriteLine("AdapterRAM: {0}", queryObj["AdapterRAM"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
                Console.WriteLine("VideoProcessor: {0}", queryObj["VideoProcessor"]);
            }
```

Получаю я в итоге:

> The type or namespace name 'ManagementObjectSearcher' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Импорт System.Management есть. (System.Management.dll не находит, хотя где-то писали, что это решение проблемы.)

Чего мне делать? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываете свой проект, кликаете правой кнопкой мыши по References в обозревателе решений для данного проекта. В выпадающем списке выбираете "Add Reference". Перед вами появляется диалоговое окно, в котором в панели слева выбираете раздел Assemblies. Появляется больше количество сборок. Среди них находите сборку System.Management. Отмечаете ее галкой, жмете кнопку Ок.  Ура, все работает.

Скриншот:

[image]

Comment: Ух ты, и вправду все работает, спасибо.
А какое отличие от импорта через using?

Comment: И не забудьте добавить: using System.Management; в начале файла :)

Comment: О.. а.. ок. Но почему оно не стало на меня ругаться, когда я просто импортнул через using?

Comment: дело не в отличиях. Дело в том, что с помощью синтаксиса using вы можете импортировать только те пространства имен, которые содержатся в уже подключенных к проекту сборках. Если сборка к проекту не подключена, то имена из нее вы импортировать не можете. По сути using - это синтаксический сахар - вы можете им не пользоваться вообще, записывая полные имена пространств имен, что, впрочем, неудобно.

Comment: Все, теперь ясно, спасибо!